# onClick and return

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that is giving me problems.

This one:

```
    onclick="return my_Check();"
```

and then this one:

```
    onclick="my_Check();"
```

My question is, Isn't this the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're not the same. The browser internally uses the string value of "onclick" attributes to construct a function:

```
var actualHandler = new Function( "event", attributeValue); // for IE, no "event"
```

Thus, adding the `return` keyword means that the handler function will return a value to the browser after it's completed its work on being called.  That's important if the handler wants to prevent the browser from doing any "native" action in response to the event: it can return `false` to tell the browser to do nothing.

*edit* — I got the argument order backwards but it's fixed now

Comment: @thesystem oops sorry gang I'll fix it.

Comment: I believe that Function doesnt have access to local variables...right ? and that's why jq used it when parsing json

Comment: @RoyiNamir interesting question; I'll test it and see. *edit* yes you're right; I guess it should have been obvious to me :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, the first returns the return value of the `my_Check()` function.

The second does not.

This means that the event can possibly respond to that return value. Some events are cancelled when returning `false`, and so this can have an impact on the behavior of your page.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If your `form` do `submit` and before submit you run the first one  :

- if the result is `false`, the form will **not** submit
- in the second one - it will. (even if `my_Check();` return false)

Answer (score 0):

The `return` passes on whatever `my_Check` returns to the handler. If `my_Check` returns `false`, then the event's default action is cancelled. Without it, the returned value is discarded and the default action is performed regardless.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I greatly appreciate it.